# What is the derivative of this piece wise function at $x=0$?

Tags: derivatives, piecewise-continuity

I was to find the derivative at $x=0$.

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1-\cos(x)}{x},  & \text{if $x\ne 0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x$ is equal to zero}
\end{cases}$$

I approached the solution by taking the following limit as for the derivative of the above function to exist at $x=0$, the limit must have existed.

$$\lim \limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
=\lim \limits_{h \to 0}\frac{\frac{1-cos(x+h)}{x+h}-0}{h}.$$

Put $x=0$, and simplify and we get this:

$$\lim \limits_{h \to 0}\frac{1-\cos(h)}{h^2}$$

Now apply the limit and we get the following fraction:

$$\frac{1-1}{0}=\frac{0}{0}=\infty.$$

So, the limit clearly doesn't exist and so as far as I can tell, the derivative of the function at x=0 also doesn't exist.

But you know what? I got zero on that question and the teacher won't tell me anything but to keep practicing to get better.

Help me understand please.

Comment: Are you familiar with and/or allowed to invoke L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: I am familiar with L'Hopital's rule but would you mind please elaborating on how would that help?

Comment: There exists a theorem which says that whenever a continuous function is differentiable in a right neighbourhood of a point and its derivative function has finite limit there, then the function is there differentiable and the derivative in that point is the limit

Comment: The illegal step is writing $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: $0/0$ is not infinity. Alternatively to the L'Hôpital rule you can use the definition of cosine as a series.

Comment: @GEdgar What does that mean? I 0/0 isn't possible which means the limit doesn't exist. And this essentially means the derivative at x=0 doesn't exist? Isnt this so?

Comment: No, you said you know l'Hopital ... that is a way to find a limit of a quotient when both numerator and denominator approach $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac00$$ is not infinity.  If I take any number $x$ and multiply by $0$, then I get $0$.  So we say that $0/0$ is undefined.

Here are the rules.

Suppose that $f(x)\to a$ and $g(x)\to b$.

- If $b\ne 0$, then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to\frac{a}{b}$
- If $a\ne 0$ and $b=0$, then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to\infty$
- If $a=0$ and $b=0$, then we can't immediately say anything about the limiting behaviour of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.  In this case, it can be useful to use L'Hôpital's rule:

> If $f(x)\to 0$ and $g(x)\to 0$ and if the derivatives of $f,g$ exist in a neighbourhood of $0$, then
>
> $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
>
> as long as the second limit exists.

Comment: Thank you so much John. Much appreciated. And as far as I can tell, it is the L'Hopital's Rule right? Are there any scenarios in which L'Hopital's also fails?

Comment: @HenrySpike Yes, there are situations when L'Hospital's rule fails.  These are spelled out in the hypotheses of the theorem:  if the derivatives don't exist, or don't go to zero, you are in trouble.  If the limit on the RHS doesn't exist, you can be in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim \limits_{h \to 0}\frac{1-\cosh}{h^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
since $\cos h=1-\frac{h^2}{2}+o(h^2)$ by taylor's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

An argument, via L'Hospital's rule, is as follows:  Note that at zero, $\frac{1-\cos(h)}{h^2}$ is an indeterminate form of the type $0/0$.  So we can apply L'Hospital to get
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(h)}{h^2}
\overset{\text{LH}}{=} \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} h} (1-\cos(h))}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} h} h^2}
= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{2h}
= \frac{1}{2} \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h}
= \frac{1}{2}.
$$

---

A more elementary approach is the following:  recall the half-angle formula
$$ \cos(2\theta) = 1 - 2\sin(\theta)^2. $$
From this, it follows that
$$ 1-\cos(h) = 1 - \left( 1 - 2\sin\left( \frac{h}{2} \right)^2 \right) = 2\sin\left( \frac{h}{2} \right)^2.
$$
Substituting this into the original limit and applying some algebraic jiggery-pokery, we obtain
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(h)}{h^2}
= 2 \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h/2)^2}{h^2}
= 2 \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h/2)^2}{4h^2/4}
= \frac{1}{2} \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h/2)^2}{(h/2)^2}. $$
As $\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta} = 1$ and the function $x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous, we have
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(h)}{h^2}
= \frac{1}{2} \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h/2)^2}{(h/2)^2}
= \frac{1}{2} \left( \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h/2)}{(h/2)}\right)^2
= \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1^2 = \frac{1}{2}.
$$